# Multiple Redis Nuget packages, which one to use for NETCORE 3.1

Tags: c#, redis, nuget

We are using .NET Core 3.1 Web API. Looks like there are multiple version of nuget packages below. Which one of these should we use for .NET CORE 3.1 web api?

1. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis
2. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis
   Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis
3. https://www.nuget.org/packages/StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.Core/
   StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.Core

At the moment we are using option 2 above for .netcore 3.1 web api. And we keep getting this error:

```
Timeout performing EXPIRE Redisat01:C910602B-A27A-4D5A-8295-B5C79A376B6A_resultspage_GetSearchCriteria, inst: 0, queue: 0, qu: 0, qs: 0, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 0, ar: 0, clientName: RD0003FF85FAF4
```